# Opengl Viewing matrix based on inputs

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vector

I'm given the camera position, camera aim point and up vector through user input. The user inputs 3 doubles for each for x y z. And now I'm trying to find the z vector and y vector which I can then normalise. I'm just struggling to figure out how to find those values and I'm not fully sure what the user inputs actually mean in terms of coordinates. I have each input stores as a Vector3d

Answer (score 0):

I was also in need of a solution to this and I ended up using a javascript library called `gl-matrix` that comes with a `targetTo` helper function.

Here's the source code for it:
http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.js.html#line1708

And here's my attempt to convert it to C.
Disclaimer: I didn't compile this, so if you find syntax errors pls mention them in the comments.

```
#include <math.h>

float *targetTo(float *out, float *eye, float *target, float *up) {

  float eyex = eye[0],

    eyey = eye[1],

    eyez = eye[2],

    upx = up[0],

    upy = up[1],

    upz = up[2];

  float z0 = eyex - target[0],

    z1 = eyey - target[1],

    z2 = eyez - target[2];

  float len = z0 * z0 + z1 * z1 + z2 * z2;

  if (len > 0) {

    len = 1 / sqrt(len);

    z0 *= len;

    z1 *= len;

    z2 *= len;

  }

  float x0 = upy * z2 - upz * z1,

    x1 = upz * z0 - upx * z2,

    x2 = upx * z1 - upy * z0;

  float = x0 * x0 + x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;

  if (len > 0) {

    len = 1 / sqrt(len);

    x0 *= len;

    x1 *= len;

    x2 *= len;

  }

  out[0] = x0;

  out[1] = x1;

  out[2] = x2;

  out[3] = 0;

  out[4] = z1 * x2 - z2 * x1;

  out[5] = z2 * x0 - z0 * x2;

  out[6] = z0 * x1 - z1 * x0;

  out[7] = 0;

  out[8] = z0;

  out[9] = z1;

  out[10] = z2;

  out[11] = 0;

  out[12] = eyex;

  out[13] = eyey;

  out[14] = eyez;

  out[15] = 1;

  return out;

}
```

Note: you might want to use `double` instead of `float`
Or if you're working with `std::vector<int>` that could also be used as the parameter.